# Django contact form doesn't show up

Tags: django, forms, contacts

I'm trying to make the contact form that is found in the django tutorial but unfortunately the form doesn't show up with {{ form }}. The only thing that shows up is the submit button. Below you can find the code:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
# Create your forms here.

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from contact.forms import ContactForm
# Create your views here.

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']

            recipients = ['myemail@outlook.com']

            send_mail(name, email, message, recipients)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contact-thanks'))
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'contact/contact-form.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

**contact-form.html**

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: That means your view works only for rendering html page but did not 'from' , so now you should test something,return render(request, 'contact/contact-form.html', {
        'form': form,'test':'this is for testing purpose',
    })                                                                          and in your html page print {{test}}

Comment: Seems like your form is not initialized. Try `form = ContactForm()` and then `if request.method` part without `else` and see it works.

Comment: @hizbul25 Still doesn't show 'this is for testing purpose'!

Comment: @sagarchalise Same thing happens, form doesn't show up.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong in my urls.py @hizbul25 ?
`url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact/contact-form.html'), name="contact")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days, I finally got the solution. The error was in the urls.py file. (So next time I will include urls.py as well) Thanks for helping guys!

I was using a TemplateView:

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact/contact-form.html'), name="contact-form"),
```

Instead of adding the view I created so that it would be possible to show and process the form.

```
url(r'^$', 'contact.views.contact', name="contact"),
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not good practice to use template_name inside url.
try with this :

```
url(r'^/contact$','appname.views.contact',name='contact')
```

Comment: Got confused! Is this the same with the answer I posted?

Comment: just change your url . but everything may be all right.

Comment: But this urls.py is inside the app contact and the url for the app 'contact' is already 'contact' so that's why I didn't add it to contact/urls.py. To avoid the url /contact/contact.

Answer (score 0):

This should work..

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']

            recipients = ['myemail@outlook.com']

            send_mail(name, email, message, recipients)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contact-thanks'))
    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    args = {'form' : form}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'contact/contact-form.html', args)
```